# make enemy follow flare

Tags: unity-game-engine, flare

```
#pragma strict

var flare : GameObject;
var speed : float = 1;

function Start () 
{
    flare = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("flare");
}

function Update () 
{

    var distance = Vector3.Distance(flare.transform.position, transform.position);

    if (distance < 100)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Enemy is close to flare");

        var delta = flare.transform.position - transform.position;
        delta.Normalize();

        var moveSpeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = transform.position + (delta * moveSpeed);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Not close yet" + distance);
    }

}
```

This is the script I have, when i right click on the mouse, it shoots out a flare, what I want to happen is for the enemy to go towards the flare when its active, at the moment, my enemy just ignores it. Any chance anyone knows why?

Any replies appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried so far? Does the code even run? Do you see anything written in the debug console? Have you tried removing all conditions and just run the code to update the position of the objects, do they move then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Javascript -- but in C# ( which is similar ) you can make a few changes.

```
void Start( ){
    flare = GameObject.FindObjectWithTag( "flare" ).transform;
}
void Update( ){
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(flare.transform.position, transform.position);
    if( distance < 100 ){
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards( transform.position, 
                                                  flare.transform.position,
                                                  speed * Time.deltaTime );
    } else {
        //Do otherthings
    }
}
```

Make sure that this script is either attached to the AI gameobect, or is referencing it ( I'm assuming from your script that the script is on the AI object ).